WSO2 Enterprise Integrator (wso2ei-6.6.0) - Deploying a Clustered Setup
I'm setting up a clustered environment for WSO2 EI 6.6.0 with one master node and two slave nodes. I've been following the official documentation (https://wso2docs.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/EI660/pages/6521017/Clustering+the+ESB+Profile#tab-a9c8785d-28dc-44b1-9f41-c0fcb3c08631). The documentation specifies the database configurations for node 1 and node 2, but it doesn't clearly state which databases need to be configured on the master node.
Could it be clarified which databases need to be set up in the master node's datasource configurations?
Thanks in advance!

You need to connect both Registry and User DB.

Thank you. What about the Registry Local DB? Should I create a separate one for the Master node as well?

@LilanMihiranga Do not change the Local Registry. Keep it pointing to the embedded H2 DB for all nodes.

Can you kindly direct to a related documentation since the existing one specifies to create a separate db for the local registry as well.

@LilanMihiranga Interesting, these WSO2 documents are pretty inconsistent. You can create separate DB for each node if you prefer that, but that is unnecessary. Even if you look at WSO2s K8S artifacts they have the local registry pointed to H2. https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-ei/blob/6.6.x/advanced/ei-pattern-1/confs/integrator/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml#L2

@LilanMihiranga I see the following note in the doc. It is recommended to use an industry-standard RDBMS such as Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, MS SQL, etc. for most enterprise testing and production environments. However, you can also use the embedded H2 database only for the REGISTRY_LOCAL1 and REGISTRY_LOCAL2.
